# jQuery Calculate Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an Invoicing System, using jquery.calculate.

```
        var newIDSuffix = 2;
    $(".invoice_items").delegate('#add-row', 'click', function () {

        var lastRow = $("tr.lastrow");
        var cloned = $("tr.default").clone().removeAttr('class');

        cloned.find('td#total_item_1').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('id', 'total_item_'+2);
        });

        cloned.find('input, select').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id'),
            name = $(this).attr('name');

            id = id.substring(0, id.length-1) + newIDSuffix;
            $(this).attr('id', id);
         });

        cloned.insertBefore(lastRow).find('input:text').val('');
        newIDSuffix++;
    });

        // update the plug-in version
        $("#idPluginVersion").text($.Calculation.version);

        // bind the recalc function to the quantity fields
        $("input").bind("keyup", recalc);
        // run the calculation function now
        recalc();

        $("input").bind("keyup", recalc);
        // run the calculation function now
        recalc();
```

Here's what I have done so far. http://jsfiddle.net/aliharis/VXZe8/

The problem is once I add a row dynamically, and when I enter the values to it, It doesn't update the amount column and total. But If I enter values for the dynamically added row and go back to first row and enter values, It makes the calculation including the dynamically added fields.

I couldn't figure out whats going wrong.

Comment: Instead of bind should use `.on()`, http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Answer (score 0):

add the line:

```
cloned.bind("keyup", recalc);
```

right after this line:

```
cloned.insertBefore(lastRow).find('input:text').val('');
```

to bind a click event to the new element.

.. or alternatively use .on() instead of bind here:

```
$("input").on("keyup", recalc);
```

Comment: Accept answer, no problem :)